# Run Javascript based on HTML class clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a tiny script I'm working on :)

The idea is if the span tag **just** contains `autocompleteitem` and **not** `autocompleteitem autocompleteitemwithcontainer` then it'll display the word `hello`. Right now it displays `hello` for both :(

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/L33mqqtp/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
          $(document).on('click','.autocompleteitem',function(){
            $("div").show();
        });
    });
```

How do I update my code to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
'click','.autocompleteitem:not(.autocompleteitemwithcontainer)'
```

Comment: Wow - amazing. Thank you, Ilya :-)

Answer (score 1):

They both have `.autocompleteitem` class! To obtain what you want, use a different selector, which only applies to first one:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click','.autocompleteitem:not(".autocompleteitemwithcontainer")',function(){
    $("div").show();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("span").on('click', function(){
        if(this.className == "autocompleteitem")
            $("div").show();
     });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the attribute selector syntax. That will allow you to directly match an entire attribute. This way you don't have to make a bunch of different combinations for each thing that you don't want to be selected.

Example selector: `jQuery('[class="autocompleteitem"]')`

Working Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
          $(document).on('click','[class="autocompleteitem"]',function(){
            $("div.containertoshow").toggle();
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="autocompleteitem">Should work</a><br>
<a href="#"class="autocompleteitem autocompleteitemwithcontainer">Should not work</a>

<div class="containertoshow" style="display:none;">That button does toggle me on/off!</div>
```